# Can the transposition of an arbitrarily-sized matrix be broken up to smaller transpositions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, transpose

I'm working with binary matrices. Let's assume that I have an algorithm that is very efficient in transposing 8×8 or 8×16 matrices, but I would like to transpose matrices with an arbitrary size.

After some thinking and scribbling, it seems that it's possible to break down the transposition of a big matrix to transposing several smaller matrices, but I can't prove that it's always possible with arbitrary sizes.

Comment: transpose a block matrix as if the submatrices are numbers, just transpose the submatrices too!

Comment: @user251257 That's what I thought, but I can't prove that this algorithm always produces correct results.

Comment: try to prove it for a $2\times 2$ block matrix. you only need to reorder the indices